# not sure why setAttribute() isn't working for audio element

Tags: html, audio, setattribute

In my code i want to set the attribute value for the audio element so that it changes "testing" to "working" in the paragraph element when the audio file stops playing.

I know i can create the audio element outside of the script but i need this for something else i'm doing.

The "horse.mp3" file is there because i was playing around on this page trying to get it working: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p id="test">testing</p>
  <script>
    var audio = new Audio("horse.mp3");

    audio.setAttribute("onended", "function(){document.getElementById("
      test ").innerHTML = "
      working "}");

    audio.play();
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your debugging console has errors

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to wrap your `onended` attribute to a function. Also, you were using multiple double quotation inside the attribute value. It won't work. I have replaced the double quotes with single quotes.

```
var audio = new Audio("horse.mp3");

audio.setAttribute("onended", "document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = 'working'");

audio.play();
```